# Use Laravel traditional form fields with the Livewire field component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I want form fields data along with livewire fields data in my request.
Suppose I have a basic html form along with a livewire component.

**create.blade.php**

```
<form>
<input type = 'text' name='name' placeholder = 'name' />
<input type = 'text' name='rollno' placeholder = 'rollno' />
..... //some more input fields
  @livewire('system.search-users')
<button type='submit'>Save</button>
</form>
```

**search-users.blade.php**

```
<div>
    <input
        type="text" id="user" name="q" wire:model="search" placeholder="Search Users" autocomplete="off" />
    <select multiple
        id="users">
        @foreach ($users as $user)
            <option value="{{ $user->id }}" wire:click="selectedUserHandler({{ $user->id }})">
                {{ $user->name }} @if (in_array($user->id, $selectedUsers))✔@endif
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
     // I have done this solution and am searching for a better solution.
    @foreach ($selectedUsers as $user)
        <input type="hidden" name="users[]" value="{{ $user }}" />
    @endforeach
   
</div>
```

When submitting a form from **create.blade.php**, how can I get the selected user_ids in the request and You can see that there is also a search input in which I have to search and select users.
I have already solved this but am not sure if it is the right way or not.

Comment: Is the create form also a Livewire component, or is that submitting to a regular controller?

Comment: And why can't you just put a name on the select and use that, why do you need the hidden inputs?

Comment: The create form is submitted to a regular controler and there is also a user search input before multi-select, so I want only selected users' id.